# Unable to lock administration directory, while updating from command line

Tags: apt, updates

I am new to Ubuntu and I am trying to update Ubuntu via command line .

So, there is an error occur I don't know how to figure it out. I am using Ubuntu version 15.04 [Vivid Vervet]

```
sudo apt-get update
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) 
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the text of the error into the question. That way it's searchable. That error usually means the Software Center or Updater is open. Check that neither is.

Comment: Just wait a moment, and retry, seems your machine is running the unattended upgrades at this moment. let me know if this solved it already for you so i can put an answer, if it not solved it let us know as well.

Comment: is anyother update process going on behind?? via software updater or software corner?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I'm sorry but you asking a question about an Ubuntu distribution which has reached already its end of lifetime. You might want to consider upgrading. I'm voting to close the question therefore as off-topic because its about an EOL release of Ubuntu.

Comment: i closed all the windows before updating , but it won't response

Comment: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?  @Zacharee

Comment: Its working now :D  , thanks @karel for the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something else has a lock on the package database, if you have killed off other processes they may not have cleared the lock. A simple restart should cure this for you.